Select2 ajax based results filtering based on regex on client and server side
I have implemented select2 in codeigniter for ajax based results and its working perfectly. But the challenge I am encountering is that the data in database is not sanitized e.g
E.C.G Machine
ECG Machine
E C G Machine

X-Ray Machine
XRay Machine
X Ray Machine

When I search for a string like ecg select2 populates only 1 record and I expect 3 results. Similarly for x-ray 1 record is returned and I expect 3 regardless of special characters or white spaces in the target keyword.
I know I have to sanitize that data first but due to some limitations I can not do this at the moment. Is there a way I can handle this requirement through regular expression or any custom function on client and server side. Help is much appreciated
Here is my current code
$('.search_equipment').each(function(){
            var elemX = $(this);
            if (elemX.data('mode')=="ajax"){
                elemX.select2({
                  ajax: {
                    url: '{site_url}inventory/',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                      var xRet = {
                        q: params.term, // search term
                        page: params.page,
                        atype: elemX.data("t"),
                      };
                      if (elemX.data('connected_to')){
                        xRet['parent_ids'] = jQuery(elemX.data('connected_to')).val();
                      }
                      return xRet;
                    },
                    processResults: function (data, params) {
                      params.page = params.page || 1;

                      return {
                        results: data.items,
                        pagination: {
                          more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                        }
                      };
                    },
                    cache: false
                  },
                  placeholder: 'Search for ' + elemX.data('text'),
                  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, 
                  minimumInputLength: 1
                });


            }else{
                elemX.select2({
                    placeholder: "Select a " + elemX.data('text')
                });
            }
        })

EDITS
Requirement is either I search the string e.c.g or E C G it should populate E.C.G Machine record from database as there is only 1 record of E.C.G Machine
Similarly if I search the string X-ray or xray or x ray it should populate X-Ray Machine record from database as there is only 1 record of X-Ray Machine
Now the names have been unified and no multiple records are existing in database

Even with regex, finding E C G in your database, based on the input ecg, is probably not going to be all that easy - plus, this will be a real performance drag.

Why can't you fix this by normalizing the data now? (If still displaying results in their original form is a concern - then put the normalized version into an extra column, and simply search within that, but use the value from the original column for display purposes.)

@CBroe I have unified the names of inventory and no multiple records exist now. Please go through the EDITS, if its possible

"Now the names have been unified" - unified to what?

There were multiple entries of same equipment in DB Like
ECG Machine,
E.C.G Machine,
E C G Machine,
Now the multiple names have been unified into single name as E.C.G Machine. Same goes for X-Ray Machine. Now what I want is if I search for the string e.c.g or E C G it should populate E.C.G Machine record from database as there is only 1 record of E.C.G Machine

But you are not easily going to find E.C.G Machine, when your entered search term is ecg or E C G ... It would make much more sense, if you put ecg machine into an extra field in your database, with all those "special characters" removed - and then did the same thing to the entered search term, so that even if the user enters E C G, what you will actually be searching for in the database, is just ecg.

@CBroe Thanks for the suggestion I have achieved the desired output. I have added an extra field then added a new column in the DB and copied all the data without special characters and white spaces. Whenever I get a query string from ajax field i applied regex to remove special characters and then searched in new field of DB. Thanks
